# Acer Aspire 5720g bluetooth keeps turning on on reboot

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth

İ'm using acer aspire 5720g and after every reboot bluetooth module activates by default. I just want to use bluetooth under my control. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards